# Loop over an Array of Objects and display only object property at a time in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have an array of objects. Within the objects are 2 properties: "quote" and "author". I have a container div in which I want the quotes to display one at a time on an interval of every 2 seconds. Right now it is displaying one letter at a time rather than one (quote + author) at a time. How do I get it to display one (quote + author) at a time?

```
"use strict";

/*Read JSON quotes file*/
let mainContainer = document.querySelector('.quotes');


let quotesList = [
    {
        "quote": "Whether you think you can or you think you can’t, you’re right.",
        "author": "—Mother Teresa",
    },
    {
        "quote": "Act as if what you do makes a difference. It does.",
        "author": "—William James",
    },
    {
        "quote": "What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.",
        "author": "—Zig Ziglar",
    },
];

var counter = 0;
let allQuotes;

quotesList.map(quote => {
    allQuotes = `${quote.quote} ${quote.author}`;
})

function next_quote() {
    mainContainer.innerHTML =  allQuotes[counter %  allQuotes.length];
    counter += 1;
}

setInterval(next_quote, 2000);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="quotes">Place quote here</div>
```

Comment: You are using the `map` function incorrectly. It's overriding `allQuotes` each interation.

Comment: Aside: you should not include the leading dash in the author's name — it is not part of the _data_, it is only how you want to _display_ the data. Add the dash as part of your javascript processing, or using CSS `.author::before { content: '- '; }` (you'd have to put a `<span class="author">` around the author name in your innerHTML)

Comment: @Stephen P Thank you, duly noted. Fixed this just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've minimally modified your existing code as I thought it would be helpful for you to learn.*

---

**Explanation**

`allQuotes` had not been initialised (assigned a value). I've assigned it an empty array.

`.map` returns an array whose items will be the return value from `.map`'s callback function (the function we pass as an argument to `.map`). The callback function is called as many times as there are items on the array (`array.length`).

I've made it so every item of `quotesList` (`{quote: ..., author: ...}`) is added to the `allQuotes` array.

Finally, in `next_quote` you can see how we step into the item of the `allQuotes` array with `allQuotes[counter]` - which returns the `{quote: ..., name: ...}`. Then, you can see how we further step in it with `.quote` or `.author` - retrieving the values of these properties.

Once the counter is the same as the number of quotes, it resets to zero.

**Code**

```js
let quotesList = [
    {
        "quote": "Whether you think you can or you think you can’t, you’re right.",
        "author": "—Mother Teresa",
    },
    {
        "quote": "Act as if what you do makes a difference. It does.",
        "author": "—William James",
    },
    {
        "quote": "What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.",
        "author": "—Zig Ziglar",
    },
];

var counter = 0;
let allQuotes = [];

quotesList.map((item, index, array) => {
    allQuotes[index] = item;
})

function next_quote() {
    console.log(allQuotes[counter].quote + '\n' + allQuotes[counter].author);
    counter += 1;
    if (counter === allQuotes.length) {
        counter = 0;
    } 
}

function start() {
    console.log(allQuotes[counter].quote + '\n' + allQuotes[counter].author);
    counter += 1;
    setInterval(next_quote, 2000);
}

start();
```

---

*Refactored into one function - happy to explain if you want*

```js
let quotesList = [
    {
        "quote": "Whether you think you can or you think you can’t, you’re right.",
        "author": "—Mother Teresa",
    },
    {
        "quote": "Act as if what you do makes a difference. It does.",
        "author": "—William James",
    },
    {
        "quote": "What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.",
        "author": "—Zig Ziglar",
    },
];

function start() {
    let quoteCounter = 0;
    function currentQuote() {
        console.log(quotesList[quoteCounter].quote + '\n' + quotesList[quoteCounter].author);
    }
    for (; ; quoteCounter++) {
        if (quoteCounter === 0) {
            currentQuote();
            continue;
        }
        setInterval(function() {
                currentQuote();
                quoteCounter++;
                quoteCounter === quotesList.length ? quoteCounter = 0 : null
            }, 2000);
        break;
    }
}

start();
```

Comment: @PA-GW no problem any questions let me know

Comment: the only thing I notice is there is a delay for the first item to appear.

Comment: @PA-GW edited it so there's no delay on the first item. I just put `setInterval` inside a new function. If you understand the code though I'm sure you could've thought of that ;). Is there anything in it you don't understand? P.s. This could get refactored (made shorter and perhaps easier to understand). Perhaps I'd do that another day.

Answer (score 1):

[`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, you can fix it as follows:

```js
"use strict";

/*Read JSON quotes file*/
let mainContainer = document.querySelector('.quotes');


let quotesList = [
    {
        "quote": "Whether you think you can or you think you can’t, you’re right.",
        "author": "—Mother Teresa",
    },
    {
        "quote": "Act as if what you do makes a difference. It does.",
        "author": "—William James",
    },
    {
        "quote": "What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.",
        "author": "—Zig Ziglar",
    },
];

var counter = 0;
let allQuotes;

allQuotes = quotesList.map(quote => {
    return `${quote.quote} ${quote.author}`;
})

function next_quote() {
    mainContainer.innerHTML =  allQuotes[counter %  allQuotes.length];
    counter += 1;
}

setInterval(next_quote, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="quotes">Place quote here</div>
```

Comment: It can even be a single line: `allQuotes = quotesList.map(quote => \`${quote.quote} ${quote.author}\`);`

Comment: That works great. I am comparing what I had vs what you put for learning purposes. I was never setting a value for ```allQuotes```. Thank you.

Comment: I will accept the answer in 4 minutes when S.O. allows me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified working example based off your code that doesn't need to map the quotes list:

```js
let quotesList = [
    {
        "quote": "Whether you think you can or you think you can’t, you’re right.",
        "author": "—Mother Teresa",
    },
    {
        "quote": "Act as if what you do makes a difference. It does.",
        "author": "—William James",
    },
    {
        "quote": "What you get by achieving your goals is not as important as what you become by achieving your goals.",
        "author": "—Zig Ziglar",
    },
];

let index = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  document.body.innerHTML = `${quotesList[index].quote} ${quotesList[index].author}`;
  index += 1;
  if (index === quotesList.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
}, 2000);
```